# Requried validation on submit button click

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

How can I validate inputs against the required validation for the controls when a submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is built into the WPF DataBinding model.  Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_validation) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

there is an awsome validation engine I am using called FluentValidation..its available on codeplex. its very easy to setup and for the most part really easy to use...

[Fluent Validation on Codeplex](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)